# PlotRange in ListStreamDensityPlot broken?

Tags: plotting, visualization

Forgive me if this is answered elsewhere; I was unable to find this specific issue.

For `ListStreamDensityPlot`, there are three options for `PlotRange`, which I understand to be the 'x' range, the 'y' range, and the *intensity* range for the scalar field. I have data of the following form:

```
data = {{{x1,y1},{{v1x,v1y},v1}},{{x2,y2},{{v2x,v2y},v2}...}
```

I have two sets of such data. For visualization purposes, I'm using `Clip` on the velocity norms such that they can only vary between, say, `0` and `.15`. In something like `ReliefPlot`, changing this `PlotRange` changes the color scaling, *e.g.* a range of `{0,.1}` would look more varied than if I let the range vary from `0` to `.5`:

```
rr200 = RandomReal[{0, .1}, {200, 200}];

ReliefPlot[rr200, ColorFunction -> "DarkRainbow", ImageSize -> 300, 
Frame -> False, PlotRange -> #] & /@ {{0, .5}, {0, .1}} // Row
```

[image: comparative relief plots]

However, I'm not able to replicate this behavior in `ListStreamDensityPlot`. Here's a kind of bad example that I'm sure could be constructed better:

Create a list of positions to which `{{vx,vy},v}` values will be joined:

```
pos100 = Flatten[Table[{i, j}, {i, 100}, {j, 100}], 1];
```

Create a list of said velocities:

```
rv100 = Flatten[Map[{#, Norm@#} &, RandomReal[{0, .1}, {100, 100, 2}], {2}], 1];
```

Join the two lists together:

```
testDat100 = MapThread[List, {pos100, rv100}];
```

This should result in a list such that, say, the first element looks like

```
In[1]:= testDat100[[1]]
Out[1]:= {{1, 1}, {{0.0692235, 0.0907269}, 0.11412}}
```

which is the form we want. Now, because the maximum x and y velocities were capped at .1, the maximum norm should be ~.14. However, when changing the `PlotRange`, it doesn't seem to have any effect on the coloring:

```
ListStreamDensityPlot[testDat100, Frame -> False, 
ColorFunction -> "DarkRainbow", PlotLegends -> Automatic, 
StreamStyle -> White, ImageSize -> 250, 
PlotRange -> {Automatic, 
Automatic, #}] & /@ {{0, .03}, {0, .14}, {0, .5}, {0, 1}} // Row
```

[image]

And now that I do this, I'm seeing something I didn't see in my real data—I have no idea whatsoever why the `Automatic` `BarLegend` is going down to ***-40***; I have no sense of where in the data that could even come from. Aside from that, the actual stream plots look identical, and I don't understand why that is.

I suspect that I'm not understanding what quantities are actually represented by the colors here, but I don't see why it would be anything *but* the scalar field. What's my issue, here? (I'm running v11.3.0.0 on macOS 10.14.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, you are using PlotRange incorrectly. Secondly, PlotLegends bar displays the interpolation function, which is used to smooth data. When the data set is small, the bar roughly displays the data itself, and when there are many random data, the interpolation function oscillates not in proportion to the amplitude of the data. All this can be seen on the model, which is given below.

```
pos[K_] := Flatten[Table[{i, j}, {i, 1, K, 1}, {j, 1, K, 1}], 1];
rv[K_] := 
  Flatten[Map[{#, Norm@#} &, RandomReal[{0, .1}, {K, K, 2}], {2}], 1];
testDat[K_] := MapThread[List, {pos[K], rv[K]}];
g[K_] := ListStreamDensityPlot[testDat[K], 
     ColorFunction -> "DarkRainbow", PlotLegends -> Automatic, 
     StreamStyle -> White, ImageSize -> 250, 
     PlotRange -> {Full, #}] & /@ {{1, K - 5}, {5, K}} // Row
```

[image: fig1]

Comment: >Secondly, PlotLegends bar displays the interpolation function, which is used to smooth data. [...]

Oh, that makes perfect sense! I didn't think about the error that could be introduced in the test data; that wasn't a problem for my actual data, at least.

>Firstly, you are using PlotRange incorrectly.

I see! I had incorrectly assumed that it would function like `DensityPlot` does—thanks for the correction.

Comment: @ Ben Kalziqi Thank you for the quick response.

Comment: On second thought, I don't understand the `PlotRange` here. I'm not trying to change which physical points I'm looking at (*e.g.* between 1 and 5 or 5 and 10 in the `g[10]` example), but instead, which values of the scalar field correspond to which colors in the `ColorScheme`/`BarLegend`.

Comment: It seems as if providing your list as the second argument of PlotRange just changes the 'y' extent of the plot, and the change in the coloring of the scalar field is a secondary effect. What I'd like is to say, "blue is 0, red is .15—color the interpolation according to those rules". Maybe I'm misunderstanding how this ought to work, though.

Comment: maybe this is a non-question, though. perhaps by just using `Clip` to adjust the range and using the automatic legend and plotrange values, it works as i expect it to work... it's late; i'll have to get back to it tomorrow.

Comment: PlotRange in ListStreamDensityPlot acts on the coordinates, on the limits of their variation, but not on the amplitude of the scalar function.